# Easy way to measure the amount of time inside another datetime

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I struggeling in creating a short PHP code for a (more or less) complicated problem.
I already found a solution, but it's not very nice, so maybe there is an easy way that I don't know yet.

This is the situation:

I have four datetimes given for the script. The script is calculation hours for weekend and public holiday workers, because in some times they get extra money when the work on nighttimes or public holidays.

Here are the examples:

```
$extramoneyforwork_start = "2023-03-10 00:00:00";
$extramoneyforwork_end = "2023-03-10 05:00:00";

$employeeclockedin = "2023-03-10 03:00:00";
$employeeclockedout = "2023-03-10 09:00:00";
```

So the total time the employee worked was 6 hours (21600 seconds).
But between 00:00 and 05:00 he or her would get an extra xx % for the job. As he started at 3:00 am its 2 hours (7200 seconds) extra payment time.

I would like to have something like this at the end:

```
$secondsofworkintotal = "21600";
$secondsofworkwithinextrapaymenttime = XXXX
```

My solution at the moment: An incredible "for loop" with strtotime checking the whole clocked in time and collecting seconds that are within $extramoneyforwork_start and $extramoneyforwork_end. This is a little crazy and takes a lot of time to calculate, but it works (slowly).

Does anybody know a simple and cool way the get the same result?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: diff the time between clocked-on and and extra money starting, and diff the time between extra money ending and clocked-off. Add those together to get the total time at normal rate. Then diff the time between extra money start and end, to get the time at extra rate. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: If they can ever clock on or off _during_ the overtime period, you would have to get a bit cleverer (e.g. working out which of the times is earlier and using that), but the above should work for the example in the question

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot of "if" and "else" in that case? and for example if $extramoneyforwork_start = "2023-03-10 01:00:00" and they clock in at 0:30 and clock out at 09:00 ?

Comment: What has this got to do with the sql tag?

Comment: sx = greatest of starts, ex = least of ends. extrapaymenttime = 0 if sx>ex, ex-sx otherwise.

Comment: `min(extramoneyforwork_end, employeeclockedout) - max(extramoneyforwork_start, employeeclockedin)`

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
//get value of the times
$extraTimeStart = strtotime($extramoneyforwork_start);
$extraTimeEnd = strtotime($extramoneyforwork_end);
$employeeIn = strtotime($employeeclockedin);
$employeeOut = strtotime($employeeclockedout);

//get worked time in seconds
$workedTime = $employeeOut - $employeeIn;

//short way of getting difference between (whichever is smaller : end of extra paid time or employee leaving) and (whichever is higher : start of the extra paid time or worker coming
$workedDuringExtra = ($extraTimeEnd > $employeeOut ? $employeeOut : $extraTimeEnd) - ($extraTimeStart > $employeeIn ? $extraTimeStart : $employeeIn);

//same as line above, but with if statements, instead of ternary operator
if ($extraTimeEnd > $employeeOut ) {
    $startTime = $employeeOut;
} else {
    $startTime = $extraTimeEnd;
}

if ($extraTimeStart > $employeeIn ) {
    $endTime = $extraTimeStart;
} else {
    $endTime = $employeeIn;
}

//this equals to $workedDuringExtra
$workedDuringExtraWithIfStatements = $endTime - $startTime;
```